# Correct installation of Rtools on windows

Tags: r, installation, package

I work on windows 7 Enterprise in my office and sit behind rather strict IT rules and without admin rights.

I have Rtools version 3.4.0.1962 installed under "C:\Program Files (x86)"
When I try to install an R package from source (because I want its 64 bit version) then I get the error

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Could it be that "C:\Program Files (x86)" is just the wrong place for Rtools?

The call

```
> install.packages("largeVis", type = "source")
```

gives the error:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/wkawar/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/largeVis_0.1.10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4968932 bytes (4.7 MB)
downloaded 4.7 MB

* installing *source* package 'largeVis' ...
** package 'largeVis' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/Program Files (x86)/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=c++0x -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/wkawar/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/wkawar/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/RcppProgress/include" -I"C:/Users/wkawar/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"C:/Users/wkawar/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/testthat/include" -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include" -DARMA_64BIT_WORDR_XTRA_CXXFLAGS = -DARMA_64BIT_WORD -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 2
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" -f "C:/Users/wkawar/Documents/.R/Makevars" CXX='$(CXX1X) $(CXX1XSTD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX1XFLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX1XPICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLD)' SHLIB="largeVis.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o checkfunctions.o dbscan.o denseneighbors.o distance.o edgeweights.o gradients.o hdbscan.o largeVis.o neighbors.o optics.o sparse.o test-runner.o testcfunctions.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'largeVis'
* removing 'C:/Users/wkawar/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/largeVis'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/wkawar/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/largeVis'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\wkawar\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\wkawar\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpai8yTY/downloaded_packages/largeVis_0.1.10.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘largeVis’ had non-zero exit status
```

This is my

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1
```

Comment: FWIW I've always installed Rtools directly under `C:\` and have not encountered any issues.

Comment: @nrussell how does the error with the bracket sound to you? Mabye the "(x86)" in the folder name causes the trouble ...what do you think? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure; in theory there shouldn't be any reason why you can't have Rtools installed in that location, but in practice these types of Windows file paths can be a real pain in the ass. I would suggest you avoid the headache of trying to figure out what's going wrong and how to fix it, and just install the software as `C:\Rtools`.

Comment: Thanks @nrussell I will try to persuade my IT guys ;)

Comment: I wouldn't even attempt this without admin rights.

Comment: @Roland what do you mean: the installation of Rtools or the installation of the package. Rtools are installed with admin rights (by the IT dep) and I would like to install the package myself. This should work ... at least could.

Comment: Well, your IT person didn't follow the [instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset), which say "Do not use filepaths containing spaces: you can always use the short forms (found by dir /x at the Windows command line)." I find it also a bit strange that you seem to use a 32bit Rtools version. On my system `c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++` is used.

Comment: And if you need to, you could set your path to temp, where most IT departments do not restrict access...

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution that worked for RTools 3.4.0.1964 on R 3.6.1, without having to reinstall in a different path.

Change the directory labels in your .Renviron to use the short form without spaces (building on Roland's suggestion).

```
PATH = "C:/PROGRA~2/Rtools/bin;${PATH}" 
BINPREF = "C:/PROGRA~2/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/"
```

Note that this .Renviron differs from the RTools 4.0 instructions but was adapted from another StackOverflow solution for an earlier version.

It worked fine after that, passing the tests suggested in the RTools 4.0 instructions:

`Sys.which("make")`  found the make file

`install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source")`  no longer complained about the "(" unexpected